# response.redirect of asp.net in facebook fan page

Tags: asp.net, facebook, response.redirect

I am developing a small facebook application.
I am developing it in asp.net, my application type is fbml.

I have some buttons on my form, I want to perform a response redirect. When I redirect the user, he's redirected outside of the fan page.

How can I solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for an FBML application you'll need to return a FBML tag to the client and get the redirect done on the client side.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:redirect

If you return something like this to the client it will redirect them:

```
<fb:redirect url="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/?not_in_group" />
```